How can I isolate -10 to +10 V using HCNR201 circuit?
See my circuit, it is basically an isolator circuit using HCNR201. This circuit works perfectly with DC 0 to 10 V. But now I want to isolate AC 0 to 10 V. However I have made op amp 4th pin (VEE) equal to -12  and -15 V respectively, but it fails to pass negative cycle. Where is my mistake?


LEDs can produce light with only one polarity of current, and even if it could produce light with either polarity, the photodiode cannot distinguish polarities of light.
If you want to use that particular isolation method, you could consider biasing the input so that it is always positive. You can remove the bias at the other side of the barrier if you want.
There are certainly other approaches (maybe you could use two HCNR201 and trim the positive and negative gains individually), but the bias approach is probably the most straightforward.

If you need +/-10V AC or DC but only use a single supply you can bias for use with 0 to 10V with a reference at V+/2 but attenuate as required /2.
Then use only 1 isolator with a bipolar supply to shift the output zero crossing from V+/2 back to 0V with gain x2 for +/- 10V.
The datasheet also shows a bipolar isolated design using 2 isolators each with half-wave rectification.
https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HCNR200-HCNR201-High-Linearity-Analog-Optocouplers-DS

Your schematic has an error with the Vin- on U1-A which must = Vin+ = 0V going to the LED C2 with A2 grounded.  That will not work.

